# How to write a \newenvironment with a conditional structure and one optional parameter

Tags: environments, conditionals, optional-arguments

I would like to define a new environment with an optional parameter. Currently, I have

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{propExt}[1][]{\ifx!#1! \begin{prop} 
\else \begin{prop}(Proof in \ref{#1})} 
{\end{prop}}
```

When I put the optional argument, everything works fine, e.g.

```
\begin{propExt}[label_name]
```

However, with no argument, `\begin{propExt}`, I have the error message

```
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 283.
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that `\end{prop}` is not executed if there is no argument specified, as it follows `\else`

How should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have no ending clause for the `\ifx` statement; it has the structure `\ifx`...[`\else`]...`\fi`. A naive approach to achieve what you're after would be:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{propExt}[1][\empty]
  {\begin{prop}% Start prop
   \ifx\empty#1\relax\else(Proof in~\ref{#1})\fi}% Conditionally add (Proof in~\ref{#1})
  {\end{prop}}% End prop
```

This checks whether the supplied optional argument matches `\empty` (whether this is defined or not). There are other ways of performing these checks. Most notably would be using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{propExt}{o}
  {\begin{prop}% Start prop
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{(Proof in~\ref{#1})}{}}% Conditionally add (Proof in~\ref{#1}
  {\end{prop}}
```

`xparse` provides the condition `\IfNoValueTF{<arg>}{<true>}{<false>}` where you condition on whether or not a value was supplied to `<arg>` (a single optional argument in the above case). An even simpler method (if no *false* clause is required) is to use `\IfValueT{#1}{(Proof in~\ref{#1})}`.

Comment: How to adapt the 1st solution to make the optional code `(Proof in~\ref{#1})` to be inserted as optional argument of the theorem environment, like `\begin{prop}[foo]content...\end{prop}`?